# Ramda не хочет работать без обертки в функцию

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`let isOver18 = person => R.lte(18, R.prop('age', person))`

Надо что б работало без обертки в функцию с person.

Что-то вроде `let isOver18 = R.lte(18, R.prop('age'))` - это не работает, где person использует каррирование.

Answer (score 0):

`R.where({
    'age': R.lte(18, R.__)
})`